# Pass an object to another thread with AfxBeginThread

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc, heap-memory, stack-memory

My program has a callback function which is called to handle notifications that are received in the form of objects. Because we can handle hundreds a second, this callback function handles the events by spawning a separate thread to handle each one. This is the callback function:

```
void _OnEvent(LPCTSTR eventID, CNotification cNotificaton) {
    if (_pActiveDoc) {
        Param_Event* p = new Param_Event;
        p->pDoc = _pActiveDoc;
        p->lpszEventID = eventID;
        p->cNotification = cNotification;
        AfxBeginThread(ProcessEvent,p);
    }
}
```

My query comes from the fact that is passed to the callback method is initially created on the stack, and is therefore (according to my understanding) limited to the scope of the calling method:

```
void CallingMethod(CString strEventID) {
    CNotification cNotification;
    // Fill in the details of the notification
    _OnEvent(strEventID,cNotification);
}
```

`CNotification` has a full copy constructor, and since the Param_Event object is created on the heap, my belief was that this would allow the original `CNotification` object to fall out of scope safely, with the spawned thread working from its own "private" `CNotification` object that exists until the Param_Event object is deleted with `delete`. The fact is, however, that we are getting (rare but occasional) crashing, and I am wondering if perhaps my belief here is incorrect: is it possible that the spawned thread is still accessing the original object somehow? If this was the case, this would explain the crashing by the rare occurrence of the object both falling out of scope and being overwritten in memory, thus creating a memory access exception.

Could I be right? Is there anything actually wrong with the method I am using? Would it be safer create the notification object on the heap initially (this would mean changing a lot of our code), or building a new object on the heap to pass to the spawned thread?

For reference, here is my ProcessEvent() method:

```
Param_TelephoneEvent *p = (Param_TelephoneEvent*)lParam;
    p->pDoc->OnTelephoneEvent(p->lpszEventID,p->cNotification);
    delete p;
return 0;
```

All advice welcome. Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** Copy constructor:

```
CNotification& CNotification::operator=(const CNotification &rhs)
{
    m_eamspeMostRecentEvent = rhs.m_eamspeMostRecentEvent;
    m_eamtcsCallStatusAtEvent = rhs.m_eamtcsCallStatusAtEvent;
    m_bInbound = rhs.m_bInbound;
    strcpy(m_tcExtension , rhs.m_tcExtension);
    strcpy(m_tcNumber, rhs.m_tcNumber);
    strcpy(m_tcName,rhs.m_tcName);
    strcpy(m_tcDDI,rhs.m_tcDDI);
    strcpy(m_tcCallID,rhs.m_tcCallID);
    strcpy(m_tcInterTelEvent,rhs.m_tcInterTelEvent);

    m_dTimestamp = rhs.m_dTimestamp;
    m_dStartTime = rhs.m_dStartTime;
    m_nCallID = rhs.m_nCallID;

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: No. Except the destructor changes some memory. BTW: To spawn one thread for each notification is a real bad design with a lot if system overhead. Place the event in a queue and let 1 or two worker read the queue and handle the event. Let the threads run all the time. Creating a new thread is "expensive".

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. Ah okay, well good to know my understanding is correct at least! The program used to use a worker thread, but because the event handling includes some SQL writing we found that on high-performance systems it fell behind. In fact a solution of spawning a new thread was suggested here on stackoverflow!

Comment: Spawning one thread per event is surely going to make your code run **slower**. *"We can use multithreading"* is a non-solution, commonly suggested by inexperienced developers. I'm sure you have better options, e.g. async I/O, completion ports, thread pools, alertable waits, and so on. Also, `_OnEvent` is a reserved symbol in C++, and should not be used.

Comment: Thanks we will look into those. FYI, the code doesn't actually use _OnEvent I've just renamed things for the sake of the question.

Comment: So regardless of this being a suitable model or not, is there any obvious reason why this would cause the code to crash?

Comment: No. Not in the things and code I can see. Debug.. Look at the pointer... May be somebody overwrites the memory.

Comment: If you are passing dynamically allocated objects across DLL/module boundaries, make sure to read [Potential Errors Passing CRT Objects Across DLL Boundaries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235460.aspx). Even though everything looks correct, it could still be wrong, depending on how and which CRT you link your modules against.

Comment: Re: "`CNotification` has a full copy constructor" - do you mean that it does a **deep** copy? Any chance it copies some pointers?

Comment: @VladFeinstein There are no pointers in the CNotification object, but I've added to the copy constructor to the question in case I'm missing something. Thanks!

Comment: @xMRi could you point me to some info on the specifics of why creating a new thread is "expensive"? Thanks!

Comment: Just take the time how Long it takes to Launch and wait for a thread to terminate.... Just spawn a thread that Exits immidiatly and take the time... ;) If you have hundrets von events you may have more threads than CPUs. So you waste tin creatiung and destryoing threads. A threead Need at least the Default of xMB virtial Memory. It allocates at least two System handles... a Queue Needs nothing of it at all.